# Python - resolving "descriptor 'isalpha' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'"

Tags: python, string, split

(Please note that I am a beginner and don't fully understand the details of the filter function...I got the code online and it was working on pycharm but the problem appears when trying to run the same code on Jupyter notebooks)
....

I am trying to scrape text from a website, from a string that's a combination of letter and numbers. 
I am receiving the message "descriptor 'isalpha' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'"
I looked for solutions but did not find what I need. 
I guess the solution may be to convert from unicode before acting on it...but I don't know how to do it. Maybe there's another solution?

This is my code:

```
for el in rows[1:]:
symbol = el.text.split(' ')[1]
symbol = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, symbol))
```

And this is the error response when I run it:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ce695528b3e6> in <module>()
     20 for el in rows[1:]:
     21     symbol = el.text.split(' ')[1]
---> 22     symbol = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, symbol))
     23     #print(symbol)
     24 

TypeError: descriptor 'isalpha' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

What can I do to resolve the problem and extract the info I need in plain text?
Thank you

Comment: As an aside, you *really* should be using Python 3 instead of Python 2, especially if you are just beginning.

Comment: Anyway, your `symbol` is apparently a `unicode` object, but you are using `str.isalpha`, try using `unicode.isalpha`, but really, you should just move to Python 3, where all strings are unicode, and byte-strings have their own data-type, `bytes`

Comment: Likely, your PyCharm IDE is working with a Python 3 interpreter, but your Jupyter notebook is using a Python 2 kernel. Use a Python 3 kernel instead.